# How to iterate over an object properties(dynamic) in mongo query in .find()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I want to retrieve related transaction from mongodb for a specific account.  Each transaction contains a data object showing transaction data but its properties can be different depending on type of transaction so is there a way to iterate over all properties of that data object regardless of the properties it has.
[image]

in this image data props are "from" "to" "quantity" "memo"
[image]
Here the data properties are "payer" "receiver" "quant"
Now i want to filter every document that in which the name of account shows up in any of data property (which means that transaction will be related to that account)